# Error at deploying an endpoint in SageMaker using Docker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

Good night.

I'm trying to deploy an endpoint to SageMaker from an already trained SpaCy model. To do this, I have created a Docker image in the local directory of a file, with the following structure:

```
 - SpaCyImage/
  |
  |- model/
  |      |
  |      |- trainedModel/          (folder with trained model's content)
  |
  |- inference.py
  |
  |- Dockerfile
```

The 'inference.py' file shows the following code:

```
import spacy
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
import string
import es_core_news_sm

model_local_path = './model/modelo'

def process_text(text):
    
    # LA FUNCION PROCESA EL TEXTO RECIBIDO ANTES DE ENVIARLO AL MODELO
    frasesSolicitud = sent_tokenize(text)
    
    
    frasesProcesadas = []
    nlp = es_core_news_sm.load() # Cargo el modelo entrenado en memoria

    for frase in frasesSolicitud:
        frasesSinVerbos = []
        texto = frase.lower()
        texto = texto.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        
        doc = nlp(texto)
        #print(doc)
        for palabra in doc:
            print(palabra, palabra.pos_)
            if palabra.pos_ != 'VERB' and palabra.pos_ != 'ADJ' and palabra.pos_ != 'PRON':
                frasesSinVerbos.append(str(palabra))
        else:
            #print(frasesSinVerbos)
            textoSinVerbos = ' '.join(frasesSinVerbos)
            frasesProcesadas.append(textoSinVerbos)



        productosReconocidos = []
    
        nlp1 = spacy.load(model_local_path)
        for item in frasesProcesadas:
            fraseProcesada = item.lower()
            doc = nlp1(fraseProcesada)

            spacy.displacy.render(doc, style="ent", jupyter=True)
                # Extraer las etiquetas de las entidades nombradas detectadas
            for item in doc.ents:
                productosReconocidos.append(item.label_)
    
        return productosReconocidos

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listaProductos = process_text('This is an example of sentence.')
```

The 'Dockerfile' file shows:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-bullseye

RUN pip install spacy
RUN pip install nltk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libopencv-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev

RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

# No será necesario por el momento un archivo requirements.txt.
#COPY requirements.txt /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt
#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /opt/ml/code/requirements.txt

COPY inference.py inference.py

ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM inference.py
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED TRUE

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "inference.py"]
```

The 'inference.py' file contains the code needed to access the trained model. Furthermore, it contains a function whose parameter (a text) is processed before it is launched against the model. The model has been trained to recognize various entities in a text, and if any are recognized, the function adds said entity to a list. Finally, the function returns the list.

The goal would be to be able to invoke an endpoint of this model and pass a text to it. Finally, the model would give me as output a list with the entities that it has recognized.

The Dockerfile contains the instructions needed to build the image with the dependencies needed to run the code needed in the 'inference.py' file. I am new to docker, so if I have made any mistake in this file, please tell me without problem.

At this point, I create a model in SageMaker using the address to the AWS ECR tag with the uploaded image; as well as the address to an S3 bucket with the 'model.tar.gz' file. I HAVE NOT CREATED ANY ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES.

[Model's config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xpan.png)

Next, I define the endpoint for this model, assigning the model that I just created. When I finish, the endpoint appears in the 'Pending...' status.

[Deploying model's endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAfAP.png)

However, after a while it appears as a 'Failed' status, and the error appears as a message:

*CannotStartContainerError. Please ensure the model container for variant variant-name-1 starts correctly when invoked with 'docker run  serve'*

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a model serving mechanism on the container. Please add the Sagemaker inference toolkit to your docker.

https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-inference-toolkit